# Big problem with security (JWT NodeJS), one token for all acces

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, jwt

I have a really big problem with security in my web application.
I implemented JWT token when user login to my application (REST API returns token).

In my jwt token, I have only userID. Problem is that, when I would like to login on user with ID = 1,

I can see and execute rest actions from all other users with the same token. for example:

When I looged userId = 1, I doing GET action: /api/users/1 and I have a information about user 1. But I can doing action /api/users/2, 3 etc.

All with one token. how to secure it?

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const env = require('../config/env.config.js');

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, env.SECRET_KEY);
    req.userData = decoded;
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(401).json({
      message: 'Auth failed',
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Ensure in those API endpoints that the user executing the action is the same user being updated?

Comment: Your application has to enforce your authorization rules. The code that responds to the request for user information has to check the session and verify that the acting user is authorized to see the requested information.

Comment: @zack6849, I edited my post. This bug is in all rest action (post, get, put etc...)

Comment: So edit the code that runs when those REST Endpoints are called to do what I said?

Comment: @zack6849 I add my checkAuth middleware

Comment: Your endpoint needs to be smart....it needs to have code to see that user x can do x and not y.

Comment: Do you set an expiration time for the token (`exp` claim)? You can also assign a `jti` claim with a unique identifier (like a [guid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)) and store it in a user session and when verifying the token you can check if it's not expired and that it matches to unique identifier of the user (the `sub` claim)

Comment: @AlonEitan, yes I set exp to 15min.

Comment: So you can also add a field to the user table storing a newly generated unique identifier - when the user logs in the system will generate that unique identifier and store it in the db (Or the session), the JWT will pass that identifier in the `jti` claim, along with the `sub` claim which is the user id. When you verify the JWT you need to check that the `jti` in the token matches the identifier that you stored when the user logged in. That way, if i'm changing the user ID you'll know that the token has been tampered with because  the identifier of the token won't match to the other user

Answer (score 2):

I think the best solution would be to create middleware that check the id of the sender and attach it to routes, similar to bellow

```js
const middleware = (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.params.id || req.body.id || req.query.id
  if (req.userData.id === id) {
    next()
  } else {
    res.status(403).send({message: "forbidden"})
  }
}
router.get("/api/users/:id", middleware, (req, res) => {
  // do your staff
  res.send({message: "ok"})
})
router.put("/api/users/:id", middleware, (req, res) => {
  // do your staff
  res.send({message: "ok"})
})
```